# how to create email link in xaml

Tags: xaml

how to create an email link in xaml?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<Label>
   <Hyperlink NavigateUri="mailto:test@test.com">Email me!</Hyperlink>
</Label>
```

Comment: Thanks, notJim. Looks simple. And what if i want to place it on a path?

Thanks, David